az login: Decryption failed: [WinError 87] App developer may consider this guidance
I am trying log in using az cli but i got an error:
PS C:\Users\macie\Documents\workspace> az login    
Please select the account you want to log in with.
Decryption failed: [WinError 87]  App developer may consider this guidance: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-python/wiki/PersistenceDecryptionError

How to fix that error?
my az cli versions:
PS C:\Users\macie\Documents\workspace> az --version
azure-cli                         2.61.0

core                              2.61.0
telemetry                          1.1.0

Extensions:
account                            0.2.5
ssh                                2.0.3
storage-preview                  1.0.0b1

Dependencies:
msal                              1.28.0
azure-mgmt-resource               23.1.1

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\macie\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.11.8 (tags/v3.11.8:db85d51, Feb  6 2024, 21:52:07) [MSC v.1937 32 bit (Intel)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.


It may be some corrupt files.
Remove directory "C:\Users\macie\.azure"
reboot and try again

Thanks for this. It works even without the reboot - just opened a new terminal and the problem was fixed.
